# Searchkick, search only in specific ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

In rails app I have `post` model, and relative `post_locations` model. We use searchkick to find data. When user enter location searchkick search in `location` table to find that location, that how I know `id` of location. So what I need is to search posts only where `post_location` is with already known id.

Example:

User search for Chicago, in location table Chicago have `id = 1`. I need to search in `PostLocation.where(location_id: 1).posts.search 'other search params'`. Any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to set an instance variable:

```
@post_location = PostLocation.search "*", where: { location_id: 1 }
```

If you have multiple variables, pass them into the hash.

```
@post_location = PostLocation.search "*", where: { location_id: 1, state: 'NY' }
```

Comment: I can find PostLocation just by doing so `PostLocation.where(location_id: 1)` and there is no need for search kick for that, BUT, I want to search in `Post` where are specific `PostLocation` post ids. It's quite hard to explain.